# After Press Back button On Paypal Payment Page my Cart gets Cleared in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am using paypal Payment standard the problem i am facing when i press place order button after selecting paypal as place order i am redirected to Paypal Payment Page . If i press back or close that tab  my cart gets clear .How to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a clean way. The way Magento works with PayPal Standard is that it first creates the order in your system (as pending) and then the user is directed to PayPal to pay. Once payment comes in, your order will switch to processing. However, if the user does not pay, the order will just stay in pending.  Since the order is already an order and no longer a quote (quote = cart) the user's cart is now empty. There are options of say showing the user his/her pending orders, or not deleting the quote on order creation if the order is only pending, but none of these or too clean. My suggestion would be to look into PayPal Express instead. It works basically the same except that the order is not created until payed in PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of years later, and you can use the browser history push to browser histroy to force the paypal standard cancel action

Rewrite `Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect`

and add line: `$html.= '<script type="text/javascript">history.pushState(null, null, "' . $this->getUrl('*/*/cancel', array()) . '");</script>';`

full code block:

```
class Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $standard = Mage::getModel('paypal/standard');

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setAction($standard->getConfig()->getPaypalUrl())
            ->setId('paypal_standard_checkout')
            ->setName('paypal_standard_checkout')
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setUseContainer(true);
        foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {
            $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value));
        }
        $idSuffix = Mage::helper('core')->uniqHash();
        $submitButton = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Submit(array(
            'value'    => $this->__('Click here if you are not redirected within 10 seconds...'),
        ));
        $id = "submit_to_paypal_button_{$idSuffix}";
        $submitButton->setId($id);
        $form->addElement($submitButton);
        $html = '<html><body>';
        $html.= $this->__('You will be redirected to the PayPal website in a few seconds.');
        $html.= $form->toHtml();
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/paypal_checkout_fix/enabled')) {
            $html.= '<script type="text/javascript">history.pushState(null, null, "' . $this->getUrl('*/*/cancel') . '");</script>';
        }
        $html.= '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("paypal_standard_checkout").submit();</script>';
        $html.= '</body></html>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Don't ask me why, but what this ends up having done, is that the Checkout / Cart url is no longer the last redirect in the browser (chrome) redirect history, but neither is the `cancel` action (as set in the push)

What is now in the history, is the original redirect action.

[image]

so, if the person hits back button, they will once again hit the controller action, and get re-redirected to paypal. Not ideal as they will be now stuck.

Next step is to extend the paypal controller:

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <paypal>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <ProxiBlue_Checkout before="Mage_Paypal">ProxiBlue_Checkout</ProxiBlue_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </paypal>
        </routers>
</frontend>
```

and adjust it to detect the session variable `PaypalStandardQuoteId` set by the redirect action. If it exists, forward to the cancel action.

```
<?php

require_once(Mage::getModuleDir(
        'controllers',
        'Mage_Paypal'
    ) . DS . 'StandardController.php');

class ProxiBlue_Checkout_StandardController extends Mage_Paypal_StandardController
{

    public function redirectAction()
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/paypal_checkout_fix/enabled')) {
            if ($session->getPaypalStandardQuoteId()) {
                $this->_forward('cancel');
                return $this;
            }
        }
        $session->setPaypalStandardQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypal/standard_redirect')->toHtml());
        $session->unsQuoteId();
        $session->unsRedirectUrl();
    }
}
```

I wrapped the change in an admin setting so I can disable if needed without having to push a new deploy (if any issues arise)

The variable is reset in the cancel action.

Just in case, I also placed a reset of that variable in the cart actions, after a product was added via the event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` so, if any cart actions arise, the var is cleared.